# Remove Windows 8 Upgrade Assistant space limits

Tags: windows-8, windows-8-upgrade

I was trying to upgrade my Windows 7 installation to Windows 8 via the upgrade asistant, and after it checks for incompatible programs and I choose to order it it stops telling me that I need to have 5GB of free space in my C drive.

[image]

How can I bypass this restriction, or at least tell it to download, etc. in another drive? It is impossible for me to have 5GB of free space in C due to its size and the programs I have installed.

(Note that I already deleted Internet cache and cia to have a bit more space)

Comment: I am pretty sure based on that size you are actually downloading Windows 8 at that point.  You could always just request the physical product and use that, and simply skip, the upgrade assistant.

Comment: Is that before or after the the ["Install Windows 8"](http://www.zdnet.com/the-ultimate-windows-8-upgrade-faq-7000006815/) screen where it asks if you want to "install now" or "install by creating media"? Which option did you go with?

Comment: Sorry for answering late, that appears right after I click "Order" (right after I was presented with the price) so I didn't buy it yet; I guess I'll buy the upgrade from another computer then. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its not possible to bypass that restriction Here are a few of your options

1. Remove(Uninstall) applications that you do not use any more.
2. Delete junk files.
3. Move files (Audio, Video, Documents, etc) from your C drive to another drive or a pen drive.

Comment: Unfortunately the only thing I could do from the list would be 1 (my profile is already in another drive and there're no junk files right now), but the programs (that are not many) are kind of big so it's not an option. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also move some big folders into another drive and reference them from C drive using a program called **junction** (see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx).

Of course You better should not move essential System folders. 
But for example the big programs You happen to have - they can be moved to another drive without actually uninstalling or even changing anything in their configuration since after using **junction** they will appear just as they were located directly on the C drive.

There are a few more things to check. Is the pagefile located on C? Try putting it elsewhere. Is the hibernation file enabled? (it is likely on C drive then) - disable it temporarily (using "powercfg –h off").

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't since the installer expects you to actually "install" it on that machine. So you need at least the image (to install from) and the rest of the space to install into... That is **> 2*(size of download image)**.